# onblur & onfucus on PHP echo

Tags: php, html, onblur, onfocus

This is part of my PHP code, and inside of it there is an echo that will print some HTML code, with the `onblur` and `onfocus` conditions. This code works when it's outside of `echo` but not inside of it.
I already tried to add the double quotes on the first `input` in my code (`Username` field) but it still doesn't work...
Any ideas?!

```
elseif ($_GET['register'] == "true"){ echo "

    <div class='index_register'>
        Register to Play or <a href='login.php'>login</a>
        <p></p>
        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <form action='?do=register' method='post' autocomplete='off'>
            <input class=\"input_reg\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"12\" value=\"Username\" onblur=\"if (this.value == \"\") {this.value = \"Username\";}\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == \"Username\") {this.value = \"\";}\">
            <input class='input_reg' type='text' name='email' size='40' maxlength='50' value='Email Address' onblur='if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email Address';}' onfocus='if (this.value == 'Email Address') {this.value = '';}'>
            <input class='input_reg' type='password' name='password' size='40' maxlength='12' value='Password' onblur='if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}' onfocus='if (this.value == 'Password') {this.value = '';}'>
            <input class='submit' type='submit' value='Register' name='Register'>
        </form>
    </div>

"; }
```

Comment: You really need to study what's client side and what's server side programming

Comment: I know that! But it's possible to get this to work correctly?

Comment: If you are expecting to echo something on change than answer is no, if you are expecting that onchange text is already present and it is causing issues than it's probably quotes, and the main thing is **WHY YOU ARE ECHOING SO MUCH OF HTML USING PHP?**

Comment: I need to echo! Otherwise it won't work because of my previous php code and conditions... I know I don't know how to code, but it works :P

Comment: Never echo so much HTML using PHP :)

Comment: Cramming HTML into a string for no reason is a really bad practice, and will only give headaches to any developer succeeding you.

Comment: I`m working for years with THAT ^ **REALLY BAD** practice and have no problems? &?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This code works when it's outside of echo but not inside of it.

don't use echo then

```
elseif ($_GET['register'] == "true"){ 
?>
    <div class='index_register'>
        Register to Play or <a href='login.php'>login</a>
        <p></p>
        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <form action='?do=register' method='post' autocomplete='off'>
...
        </form>
    </div>
<?
 }
```

Comment: Because of my previous PHP code I can't use it this way! That's why I'm asking for help to get it to work inside an `echo` tag.
Thank you anyway

Comment: You're right! I can get it to work like this, but it's not my intention. I accepted your answer as useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. You need to **correctly** `escape quotes` inside onblur/onfocus:

try this inside php code:

`<input class=\"input_reg\" type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"12\" value=\"Username\" onblur='if (this.value == \"\") {this.value = \"Username\";}' onfocus='if (this.value == \"Username\") {this.value = \"\";}'>`

.

`<input class='input_reg' type='text' name='email' size='40' maxlength='50' value='Email Address' onblur='if (this.value == \"\") {this.value = \"Email Address\";}' onfocus='if (this.value == \"Email Address\") {this.value = \"\";}'>`

.

`<input class='input_reg' type='password' name='password' size='40' maxlength='12' value='Password' onblur='if (this.value == \"\") {this.value = \"Password\";}' onfocus='if (this.value == \"Password\") {this.value = \"\";}'>`

Comment: That's it! :) You only change the last quote?! -_-

Comment: @RaheelHasan Code in SO can surely look good. Use Select the code, and press Ctrl+k, for format and syntax highlight your code.

Comment: .. and you just reverted the change I did!

Comment: @Thrustmaster: its within `echo ""` and hence need to look like this. see his question.

Comment: Ok. Know I see what I've been doing wrong.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RaheelHasan Please read the [formatting help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), you could format with "echo" too.

Comment: @Thrustmaster anyway buddy, thanks for Ctrl+K tip.. will be handy next time :D

Comment: @zppinto, even if this works, it is still wrong to have huge amounts of HTML in a string like that. This is really the beauty and the pain about PHP, so many ways to make something work without doing a single thing right.

Answer (score 0):

In your case [`heredoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) or [`nowdoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) syntax is prefered, when you output large blocks:

```
<?php
echo <<<HTM
    <div class='index_register'>
        Register to Play or <a href='login.php'>login</a>
        <p></p>
        <!-- Registration Form -->
        <form action='?do=register' method='post' autocomplete='off'>
            <input class='input_reg' type='text' name='username' size='40' maxlength='12' value='Username' onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Username";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Username") {this.value = "";}'>
            <input class='input_reg' type='text' name='email' size='40' maxlength='50' value='Email Address' onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Email Address";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Email Address") {this.value = "";}'>
            <input class='input_reg' type='password' name='password' size='40' maxlength='12' value='Password' onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "Password";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "Password") {this.value = "";}'>
            <input class='submit' type='submit' value='Register' name='Register'>
        </form>
    </div>
HTM;
?>
```

Comment: never echo a heredoc in PHP. It makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Heredoc System you don´t have to escape the quotes. I used the Heredoc with JavaScript embedded as if I was using plain HTML and it all works as it should.